# An element of an array doesn't pass a test

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing a function that loops through an array and tests each element for a condition. If it is false, the element is dropped. If it is true, the function returns the rest of the array.

Here is my code:

```
function dropElements(arr, func) {
    // Loop through the array
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      // if the current element passes the test, return the rest of the array
      if (func(arr[i])){
        return arr;
      // otherwise remove the element
      } else {
        arr.shift();  
      }
    }
    // if no conditions were met, return empty array
    return arr;
}
```

When the loop reaches i = 1, we have arr[1] = 2.

Since 2 is not >= 3, I do not understand why it is not dropped.

So, why does the following call

```
dropElements([1,2,3,4], function(n) {return n >= 3; });
```

return [2,3,4] instead of [3,4] ?

Thanks.

Comment: Might as well just change your `for` to a `while` and do `while (arr.length) {...` and then inside do `if (func(arr[0])) {...`. The way your code works, there's never a situation where you'll be accessing an index greater than `0`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because when you "shift" it removes the index and the other indexes shift down to fill in the hole. So when you remove the first one, the second index is now one. And since you increment `i`, you skip the index that was moved down.

So to get around your issue, you would need to reduce `i`

```
else {
    arr.shift();
    i--;
}
```

Or you can do another solution where you find the index and than just splice the array.

Comment: Wouldn't that make the variable i pointless? i will always be 0.

Answer (score 0):

From MDN doc:

> The shift() method removes the first element from an array and returns that element. This method changes the length of the array.

In your code this means that you have to sync the index in the loop. You can simply decrease the index by 1

```
function dropElements(arr, func) {
// Loop through the array
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  // if the current element passes the test, return the rest of the array
  if (func(arr[i])){
    return arr;
  // otherwise remove the element
  } else {
    arr.shift();i--;
  }
}
// if no conditions were met, return empty array
return arr;}
```

This will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the order in which you are shifting the array. Take into comparison the following:

```
function dropElements(arr, func) {
    if (!Array.isArray(arr) && arr.length == 0) {
        return [];
    }

    while (!func(arr[0]) && arr.length > 0) {
        arr.shift();
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

epascarello's answer should be accepted as the correct one, however here is an updated code block for what you need:

```
function dropElements(arr, func) {
    // Loop through the array
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      // if the current element passes the test, remove it from the array
      if (func(arr[i])){
        return arr;
      } else {
        arr.shift();
        i--;
      }
    }
    // Return the array
    return arr;
}

var arr = [1,2,3,4,2];
dropElements(arr, function(num) {
    return num >= 3;
});
```

This outputs `[3, 4, 2]` (this is because we assume that the array is ordered when we loop through it and return from the function when the test function is satisfied once).   If you want to loop on an unordered array, simply remove the `return arr` in the loop, just note that this will run at O(n) opposed to O(log n)

Comment: on long array though you break out of loop much faster returning the way OP is doing...assuming array is sorted

Comment: I wasn't sure if the OP was always testing through an ordered array, it wasn't specified as a requirement in the initial question so: `1, 2, 3, 4, 2` would contain an invalid digit.  My bad!

Comment: have to assume it is sorted or they wouldn't be returning the rest of the array right way

Comment: Yep, totally an oversight by me!  Updated to reflect your suggestion - cheers